# After saving an object using mongoose, what is the simplest way I can return an object with a subset of fields?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose with express and node to create a REST API.  Upon saving a new object, I want to return the object to the user.  However, do not want to return some sensitive fields, like password, credit card details, permissions, billing history, etc.

I thought that there would be the equivalent of .select where you can select just a subset of fields to return to the user.  However, it looks like this does not exist, and the 'standard' is just to delete fields you do not want to pass back to the user, like so:

```
  org.save(function(err, org) {
    if (err) return handleError(err, res);
    orgobj = org.toObject();
    delete orgobj.__v;
    delete orgobj._id;
    delete orgobj.billing;
    delete orgobj.plans;
    delete orgobj.permissions;
    return res.send(orgobj);
  });
```

Is there a more efficient way?  I don't like this, because if there is subsequently a field added, someone has to remember to specifically remove it.  Also, I don't want to 're-select' the field either, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may add a method, `getPublicFields` which returns an object containing strictly the public fields.

```
orgSchema.methods.getPublicFields = function () {
    var returnObject = {
        name: this.name,
        address: this.address,
        randomField: this.randomField
    };
    return returnObject;
};
```

You may also add a callback to that function and perform some other queries to aggregate data, if you wish to do that. After the method is complete, just call

```
var orgPublic = org.getPublicFields();
```

Comment: Perfect.  Works brilliantly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still interested in a more mongoose friendly answer see the following.

When you use `.select(...)` you can see that the mongoose doc still has all its fields and the `_doc` property is the one to be reduce.

What you can do is after saving a new doc remove the fields you want out of `newDoc['_doc']`.

Now you are able to use the `newDoc.toObject()` to pull the "public" fields you specified.

In the example below I'm using `_.pick()` to create a white list the fields I want, but you can use `_.remove()` to create a black list as well.

Note that the `publicFileds`array can be use in the `.select(...)` for querying so you only need one `publicFileds` definition for your CRUD actions.

```
var MyModel = require('./MyModel');
var _ = require('lodash');

var publicFileds = ['_id', 'name', 'age'];

function create(newModelData, cb) {

    var newModle = new MyModel(newModelData);

    newModle.save(function (err, newDoc) {

        if (err) {
            cb(err);
            return;
        }

        newDoc['_doc'] = _.pick(newDoc['_doc'], publicFileds);
        cb(null, newDoc);

    }
}
```

Comment: Well if you really want some actual technichal advice then the answer using `.select()` here ( which I just upvoted because it's the only correct one of the bunch really ) need only add `.lean()` to in fact return **even less** than what you seem to think is a good idea here. It really isn't that great an idea, and in fact [`.lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) is the recommended thing to do if you don't need access to any of the object methods and simply want a plain object. Doesn't need the "hoop jumping" you suggest here.